# Is there recommended way to run async wsgi on Python3?

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi, gunicorn, gevent

On Python3, I can't use gevent as wsgi.
Is there any way to run async wsgi like gevent on Python3.
I uses wsgi as gunicorn and runs on CentOS 6.6.

When I tried gevent 1.1b3 with gunicorn, I got these error.

```
$ python manage.py gunicorn -k gevent
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13636] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13636] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (13636)
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13636] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13640] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13640
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13640] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 185, in init_process
    self.patch()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 74, in patch
    _sock=s))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_sock'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 185, in init_process
    self.patch()
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 74, in patch
    _sock=s))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_sock'
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13640] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13640)
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13636] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2015-08-19 14:20:48 +0900] [13636] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Upgrading the gunicorn to latest version 19.4.5 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use 'gevent'? What is the problem?

Yes, the Python 3 support is in beta at this time, but I am sure gevent developers would love to hear of any problems with the upcoming Python 3 support.

```
pip install 'gevent==1.1b3'
```

Comment: You should perhaps take this up with the gunicorn developers on the github issue tracker for gunicorn, or on the gunicorn group on IRC. As in, it looks to be an issue with gunicorn and latest gevent beta versions. They may well have a fix but not yet in released gunicorn version.

Comment: I found already someone submitted the pull request and that was merged into master on gunicorn.   
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/1066

I also found eventlet works fine with gunicorn on python3.